# PHP - DateTime gmt offset to float format

Tags: php, date, datetime

```
$gmt_offset = get_option("gmt_offset",""); // 3.5 for example
$timezone_string = get_option("timezone_string",""); // America/Caracas for example
if(!empty($timezone_string)){
    $tt = new DateTimeZone($timezone_string);
    $time = new DateTime('now', $tt);
    $gmt_offset = $time->format('O');
 }

    return $gmt_offset;
```

I am trying to get gmt offset in float format, where

3.5 hour is represented as (float)3.5

3 hours 15 minutes is (float)3.25

The problem is that DateTime::format() function does not have such format, and I could not find any relevant question.

Comment: Just split the returned value, divide the minutes digits by 60 and then add it to the hours

Comment: Looks like I found the way by doing $gmt_offset = $time->format('Z')/3600;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$gmt_offset = get_option("gmt_offset",""); // 3.5 for example
$timezone_string = get_option("timezone_string",""); // America/Caracas for example
if(!empty($timezone_string)){
    $tt = new DateTimeZone($timezone_string);
       $time = new DateTime('now',$tt);
      $gmt_offset_h = $time->format('H');
      $gmt_offset_m = (int)($time->format('i')*100/60);
      $gmt_offset = $gmt_offset_h .'.'. $gmt_offset_m;
 }

     return  $gmt_offset ;
```

hope this will help you

Edit: Added $gmt_offset in if condition to return valid value of $gmt_offset if value $timezone_string is empty

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
// use P (+02:00), in stead of O (+0200), for easier splitting.
$offset_parts = explode( ':', $time->format( 'P' ) );
$gmt_offset = floatval( $offset_parts[ 0 ] . '.' . ( ( $offset_parts[ 1 ] / 60 ) * 100 ) );
```